# How to detect collisions only one-way?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, game-physics

Okay so lets say you are trying to make a game like Super Smash Bros. How would one make it so you can jump up and go through a floating platform, but also so you can't fall through it in Unity 3d?

Comment: Say a character has a floor collider and a rigidbody: `collider.enabled = rigidbody.velocity.y <= 0;`. This way, if a character is moving upwards, collider is disabled so they'll go through any platform. But if character is falling, collider is enabled and they'll land on a platform.

Comment: For the love of all that is holy shorten the title.

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans sorry, I sometimes do that. My bad haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach this C# script to your platform and you can choose whether to allow players to only  jump above your platform (topCollision= true) or to only fall through your platform (topCollision = false). Also your platform must have a mesh collider for the script to work. Taken from http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/236313/one-way-collider.html

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent (typeof (MeshCollider))]
public class PlatformCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool topCollision = true;
    public float maxAngle = 45.0f;

    void Start ()
    {
        float cos = Mathf.Cos(maxAngle);
        MeshCollider MC = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
        if (MC == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("PlatformCollision needs a MeshCollider");
            return;
        }
        Mesh M = new Mesh();
        Vector3[] verts = MC.sharedMesh.vertices;
        List<int> triangles = new List<int>(MC.sharedMesh.triangles);
        for (int i = triangles.Count-1; i >=0 ; i -= 3)
        {
            Vector3 P1 = transform.TransformPoint(verts[triangles[i-2]]);
            Vector3 P2 = transform.TransformPoint(verts[triangles[i-1]]);
            Vector3 P3 = transform.TransformPoint(verts[triangles[i  ]]);
            Vector3 faceNormal = Vector3.Cross(P3-P2,P1-P2).normalized;
            if ( (topCollision && Vector3.Dot(faceNormal, Vector3.up) <= cos) ||
                 (!topCollision && Vector3.Dot(faceNormal, -Vector3.up) <= cos) )
            {
                triangles.RemoveAt(i);
                triangles.RemoveAt(i-1);
                triangles.RemoveAt(i-2);
            }
        }
        M.vertices = verts;
        M.triangles = triangles.ToArray();
        MC.sharedMesh = M;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd rather use JavaScript, but do I need to modify this script for it to work?

Comment: No, I tried out the script myself. All you need to do is create a file called PlatformCollision.cs and attach it to your platform